# RHEL 8.5 Bash v4.4.20 & SSH invoking .bashrc twice

Tags: bash, ssh

I recently installed a new remote host that runs RHEL 8.5. The rest of my environment is RHEL 7.4. I noticed a strange thing when I ssh to the RHEL 8.5 host. It seems like my `.bashrc` is getting called twice.

Here's the behavior:

- From my gateway I ssh to the RHEL8.5 host using the below command:

  ```
  ssh -t user@rhel85host "IAM=peaves CONTROL=simulation bash -i"
  ```
- As a debugger I put "Hello World" as the first line in my `.bashrc`. I get the following output

  ```
  Hello World

  Hello World
  ```
- I tried removing the `-i` on the Bash call but it's the same behavior (`Hello World` twice).

It seems like a bash shell is getting created first but the two items I'm passing cause bash to be called again.

Has anyone dealt with this before? Any tips on the ssh login or bash call to make it not do that and behave like RHEL 7.4?

Comment: Please add a complete copy of your `.bashrc` into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Passing a command via SSH **always** runs it via the shell, using e.g. `/bin/bash -c "the command"`. That's how OpenSSH has always worked (since day one, I believe, to mimic rsh).

What might have changed is how RHEL compiles bash – for some reason, bash has a *compile-time option* whether to load .bashrc when it is being run with the `-c` option over an SSH connection. (Yeah, it specifically checks if it's being started by sshd.) Debian enables this mode; Arch does not; and it *sounds like* RHEL has started enabling it.

There's no way to opt out of the first invocation (except by changing the user's login shell to something other than bash), but you could have the .bashrc set an environment variable that tells it "already run once". For example:

```
if [[ $_BASHRC_RUN ]]; then
    return
fi
export _BASHRC_RUN=1
```

However, .bashrc in general is not the right place for expensive "login" tasks – those should go in .profile or .bash_profile instead, while .bashrc should only contain stuff like aliases or environment variables at most.

Comment: I wouldn't say I am doing anything expensive in .bashrc except sourcing another profile which sets some environment variables. I will try as you suggested and report back tomorrow!